# Difference between .ocx file and a .Net Control

Tags: .net, mfc, ocx

What is the difference between an .OCX file created in MFC or VB and a .Net control created in C#?

1. Is it possible to use the .Net
   Control in a MFC application?
2. I have a  dialog in C# I need to use
   the same dialog in MFC.whether can I
   import the entire dialog into Mfc
   ,or can i save my C# application as
   .OCX file and use it in MFC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference: .ocx is unmanaged because MFC is unmanaged, .NET controls are managed (if you don't try to use MFC in .NET, or other unmanaged stuff).

I think you can't save your .NET app as .ocx file, at least there is no standard way to do this, but you can still use .NET controls in C++ because they can be registered for COM interop.